# kafka installation failed with Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to 6667

Tags: apache-kafka, failed-installation

I am installing kafka using ambari.

While installation i got an error:

Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to localhost:6667.

Can someone help in this.